# Google cloud storage connector within sparkR on dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I see that the gs:// interface is available within spark and pyspark on the dataproc cluster but doesn’t work in the SparkR shell. Is there a way to make it work? The path is simply not found if you run it. I am aware of the cloudyR project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gs:// interface should work in the sparkR shell on Dataproc, if you use it in the [DataFrame read interface](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-dataframes) e.g.

```
> df <- read.parquet("gs://public-datasets/natality/parquet/")
> printSchema(df)
root
 |-- source_year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- month: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- wday: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- is_male: string (nullable = true)
 |-- child_race: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- weight_pounds: double (nullable = true)
 |-- plurality: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- apgar_1min: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- apgar_5min: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- mother_residence_state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mother_race: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- mother_age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- gestation_weeks: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lmp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mother_married: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mother_birth_state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cigarette_use: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cigarettes_per_day: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- alcohol_use: string (nullable = true)
 |-- drinks_per_week: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- weight_gain_pounds: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- born_alive_alive: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- born_alive_dead: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- born_dead: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ever_born: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- father_race: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- father_age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- record_weight: integer (nullable = true)
```